# Cartthrob - Discount per product

Tags: cartthrob, discounts

I try to setup a simple discount with a existing plugin (Amount off) per product.

I want to apply the discount only to one product.

I setup a All store discount with the channel "Store - discount" this is working. But this is not what I want since it not all product that are in discount.

I add a custom field Discount in my "products" channel field groups I put the type "Cartthrob Discount settings". The configuration for the discount in the product entry are there I can choose the discount type. But nothing happen in my cart. Did I miss something? Did is supposed to work?

Thank in advance

AK

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector; we own CartThrob)

You say you want to apply "the discount to only to one product." But you also say it might be applying to all products. Is it possible you chose the discount type "Amount off" instead of "Amount off product", which lets you specify just certain products?

"CartThrob discount settings" should be its own field in a "Store - Discounts" channel (that's how CartThrob sets it up for you). It shouldn't be attached to the product. In there, you make store-wide discount settings, however you can use the "product" discount type for it to only apply to certain products.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Hi Matt Sorry for the delay I was in vacation. To be clear I want to apply discount to only specific product not all at the same time. But now I have a bigger problem when I try to create a "Store Discounts" entry I have a Internal server error.

Comment: @AlexK you can do that with a discount type of "Percentage off a single product", and entering the proper entry_id.